# How do I convert a cloglog stats family object to a scale transformation in R?

Tags: r

I would like to use cloglog as a scale_y_continuous transformation option in ggplot2; that function is inside `binomial(link="cloglog")` - how can I easily convert the stats `family` object to a `transformation` object?

Ideally as a reusable function in case I need to change the link later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it. It could be improved by creating a custom breaks function, or finding one that already exists (the built-in `logit_trans` doesn't look any prettier ...)<sup>1</sup>

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

cc <- make.link("cloglog") ## don't actually need family() here
cloglog_trans <- function () {
    trans <- function(x) cc$linkfun(x)
    inv <- function(x) cc$linkinv(x)
    trans_new("cloglog", trans, inv)
}
```

### example

```r
dd <- data.frame(x = runif(100), y = runif(100))
ggplot(dd, aes(x, y)) +
    scale_x_continuous(trans = cloglog_trans()) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Alternately, you can do this by definining a complementary Gumbel distribution and using `probability_trans`:

```r
pcgumbel <- function(x) VGAM::pgumbel(-x,lower.tail = FALSE)
qcgumbel <- function(x) -1*VGAM::qgumbel(x, lower.tail = FALSE)
ggplot(dd, aes(x,y)) +
    scale_x_continuous(trans = probability_trans("cgumbel")) +
    geom_point()
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: I would love to have a good probability-scale breaks generator, if someone can point to one - although I would be careful which audiences I was communicating with when using a probability transformation ...